# InvalidCastException with Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, for-loop, dictionary, foreach

I'm having some issues filling a dictionary and afterwards putting the data in a ListBox.
Here's my code:

```
Dictionary<int, int> items = new Dictionary<int, int>();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, c.Connection);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) {
     //InvalidCastException HERE
     items.Add((int)rdr["artikel_id"], (int)rdr["sum(aantal)"]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++) {
     if (items.ElementAt(i).Value <= 0) {
           listBoxStrings.Add("artikel_id: " + items.ElementAt(i).Key + ", besteld: " + items.ElementAt(i).Value);
     }
}

foreach (string s in listBoxStrings) {
//listbox
     lb.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `artikel_id` column?

Comment: both are integer in my db

Comment: This looks strange `(int)rdr["sum(aantal)"]`, did you mean `(int)rdr["aantal"]`?

Comment: Are `artikel_id` or `sum(aantal)` nullable in your database?

Comment: no, I think `(int)rdr["sum(aantal)"]` is correct, because it's the name of a table my query returns. I could also use `select sum(aantal) as aantal` and use your `(int)rdr["aantal"]`, but I think that's the same

Comment: Both of the columns have values in it.

Comment: Post the `query1` code.

Comment: [this is what the query returns](http://puu.sh/heIGp/ff7c17ac2c.png)

Comment: can you actually use `sum` in that way?

Comment: Can you edit in the SQL query that you are executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that rdr["artikel_id"] and rdr["sum(aantal)"] are both not null.

If they both are not null, verify their runtime type by doing rdr["artikel_id"].GetType().FullName and check that you can actually cast it to Int32.

Comment: artikel_id is System.Int32 and sum(aantal) is System.Decimal

Comment: Try to change your `Dictionary` to `<int, decimal>` ?

Comment: Problem solved by combining these 2 answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were not pulling your column correctly.  Try this, see if/where it exceptions.

```
Dictionary<int, int> items = new Dictionary<int, int>();

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query1, c.Connection);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) {
     //InvalidCastException HERE
     int value1 = (int)rdr["artikelid"];
     int value2 = (int)rdr["besteid"];

     items.Add(value1,value2);
}
```

Comment: Problem solved by combining these 2 answers. Thanks!